# Set git globally add certain files of type

Tags: git, gitignore, git-add

I want to setup git to stage only certain files of type.
With

```
git add *
```

in basic dir, i must stage only the files of type cpp,h,txt,html.
How i must do this?

Comment: Instead of `git add *`, list the filenames you want to add.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+ignore+except+some

Answer (score 0):

Just use wildcard `*` like this:

```
git add *.cpp
git add *.h
git add *.txt
git add *.html
```

`*` matches any number of characters, so pattern `*.txt` will match ale files with names ending with `.txt`.

To make this even easier, you can set your own git alias to add only certain files:

```
git config --local alias.addHtmlFiles 'add *.html'
git config --local alias.addTextFiles 'add *.txt'
git config --local alias.addCppFiles 'add *.cpp'
git config --local alias.addHeaderFiles 'add *.h'
```

Now you just use

```
git addHtmlFiles 
git addTextFiles 
git addCppFiles 
git addHeaderFiles
```

to add wanted files.

Comment: Thank you, but i am looking for a global setting. You know, sometime maybe use git add * by mistake, and then all, maybe thousandths of files add to stage. I am looking a way to set git to do it globally. Can i use for example git config --local alias.addHeaderFiles 'add *.h|*.cpp|*.html|*.txt' ?